# How to publish Azure function app application settings from visual studio based on publish profile

Tags: azure-functions, publish, visual-studio-2019, azure-application-settings

I created function app in visual studio and able to publish successfully. But It needs manual configuration settings in azure portal (cloud).

example scenario: Let's say If we have connection string in settings, it varies on environment basis.
I have requirement to publish to different environments.

Is there any way to publish application settings / configurations along with publish rather going to portal and updating application settings?

Publish to different environments is working with different publish profiles. But makes me to go and create / update application settings in portal manually.

Expecting, If I select publish profile it should publish my function app along with given application settings as well. It should work as expected without going to portal and updating any settings.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can use `Powershell`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp?view=azps-2.3.2. `ARM template`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites or `Az Cli`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ARM TEMPLATE` and deploy your `FunctionApp` with any Application settings as per your needs. -> [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code#create-a-function-app)

The quick start template can also be found here on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-function-app-create-dynamic)